# best way to read data from firestore using unreal engine's VaRest plugin?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, unreal-engine4

what's the best way in unreal engine 4 using VaRest plugin to read data from firestore?

Answer (score 0):

following are the blueprints and layout of my firestore information. if there is a better way, post your blueprints if you please.

[image]

[image]